# Test tank physics

Tags: fluid-dynamics, dimensional-analysis, viscosity, turbulence, scaling

In a test tank scaled-down simulation of, for example, a ship stability problem, is it not incorrect to assume that water will behave in a scaled-down fashion with regard to wave period? Don't we need to use a liquid of (I'm guessing) lower viscosity to accurately represent real-world behaviour in the scaled-down model?

Answer (score 0):

You are right- there are a number of scaling parameters called *nondimensional groups* or *similitude parameters* which tell you by how much the viscosity, density, and surface tension of the liquid must be scaled to match the length scaling factor so the miniature-scale model behaves (to scale) just like the full-scale model would. This is true for ship hull models and gravity waves in water.

That said, I do not know which particular nondimensional group (weber number, froude number, reynolds number, nusselt number, etc.) to use in this case and will rely on one of the experts here to furnish that part of the puzzle.

Comment: Be careful in the selection of the fluid.  I doubt that any fluid other than water is non-flammable, non-poisonous, and environmentally benign all at the same time.